# strconv.Itoa(time.Nanoseconds()) - Error

Tags: go

I write one go code like this, `strconv.Itoa(time.Nanoseconds())`. But, it is giving me this error "cannot use time.Nanoseconds() (type int64) as type int in function argument". How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := strconv.FormatInt(time.Nanoseconds(), 10)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Output:

```
1322756865962046000
```

Answer (score 2):

if you got an error like this, just cast it the way the compiler told it.
i.e.:

```
strconv.Itoa(int(time.Nanoseconds()))
```