# strconv.Itoa64(1234) gives undefined in golang

Tags: go, int64, uint64

**This is my code:**

```
package main
import (
    "strconv"
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    t := strconv.Itoa64(1234)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

**Problem:**

Why does it cause the following error message?

> command-line-arguments .\test.go:7: undefined: strconv.Itoa64
>   [Finished in 0.2s with exit code 2]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is because Itoa64 is not the name of a function in the strconv package. It looks like you really want.

```
t := strconv.FormatInt(1234, 10)
```

See http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatInt

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen, it is working! There is some **confusing** info on this subject, including: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344210/strconv-itoatime-nanoseconds-error/8344775#8344775 and http://golang.org/src/cmd/fix/strconv_test.go

Comment: `strconv.Itoa64` existed before Go 1. That is why there is conflicting information.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I often have trouble finding info while coding in go. What is your main source of info while coding in Go?

Comment: The IRC channel is a great source of help. Other than that I normally just use the spec, docs, and the code.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert like this

```
func main() {
    t := int64(1234)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.